# Imaging HP Laptops using WDS server

Tags: windows-7, laptop, deployment, imaging, wds

I am using a 2008 r2 server to run as my Windows Deployment service. I have imaged successfully desktops. I am now trying to deploy an Image to hp Laptops and am finding that after the imaging has finished and a reboot is required the machine does not come up and starts looping to which it asks for the "Last Known Good" but no matter what is selected it still starts & then reboots without fully booting.
I have tried injecting drivers in to the boot image with no luck & I have tried a vanilla boot image with no extra drivers at all and still no luck. The only thing that may be a problem with my boot image is that it is an Enterprise version as none of the HP laptops come with Enterprise recovery disk (for obvious reasons) so may not have some special drivers!

Comment: Where did this image come from that you are using to deploy Windows onto the laptops?  Did you install Windows first normally onto one of the laptops, make an image of that installation, and use that?  Or are you using an image from the desktop installation on the laptops?  It sounds as if there is a hardware conflict from drivers in the image that is causing the Laptope to BSOD and restart... just quickly so that you cannot actually see the BSOD.

Comment: No I have built the Laptop from scratch - ie. loaded a Windows 7 Enterprise disk. Built the machine as to how I want it and then sysprep'd it. I have tried capturing the Image 2 ways 1) by booting from a USB stick and using Imagex (I have been using gimagex) and then putting this upto my WDS server. 2) I have been using the Capture Image functionality that teh WDS server can use to capture the image straight to the WDS server. Both ways have meant I have ahd to sysprep the machine first. Sorry what is BSOD?

Comment: Blue Screen of Death.  Standard Windows error screen that will show an error code pointing to what is causing the issue.  Windows by default is set to restart upon hitting one of these, and modern equipment is fast enough where most people won't even see it.  All the laptops are identical?  Actually that shouldn't make a difference after Sysprep... But the fact that it is Enterprise also should make no difference.  If you could, you should set up another image from scratch, but BEFORE sysprep, turn off the automatic restart on error feature.

Comment: Duh yeah I should know that one! Yes I didn't click as it did not get that far to show any BSOD as windows had not loaded fully.I will try turning the auto restart off & get back to you.

Comment: OK I have re-imaged and the BSOD says I have a disk problem - Check for virues on your computer. Remove any newly installed hard drivesor hard drive controllers. Check your hard drive to make sure it is properly configured and terminated. Run CHKDSK /F to check for hard drive corruption, and then restart your computer. I have treid restarting and starting in "Safe" mode but it gets to loading disk.sys and then I get the BSOD. I suspect it is an HP problem in the way they access their disk drives but cannot find any drivers or information about it.

Comment: It could be that Sysprep is removing any and all HP specific SATA drivers necessary to properly detect and access the hard drive.  Are all these laptops the same model?

Comment: I am testing with the same model but all models that we have here I have had the same problem and I cannot image using the WDS service so I suspect the same problem with all of them. The odd thing is that I save the image to an external hard drive as well as putting it on the WDS server and I can use gimagex to apply the image back onto another laptop and it works prefectly.

Comment: Then at some point during the process that fails, the image is getting corrupted.

Comment: How do I fix it? I can image a desktop using exactly the same methods & even the same enterprise disk etc.

Comment: @GregFuller If it works from a USB drive and not from the network, I would suspect the NIC driver in your boot image. You said in your OP that you injected drivers, but didn't say which drivers you injected... so I wanted to ask.

Comment: I have injected most if not all "updates" from the HP support web site (for the models in question) as well as Display drivers & NIC drivers. Probably the only ones I have not injected would be BIOS, modem & others that I deemed unnecessary.